# How to list public groups of a user in Gitlab?

Tags: api, gitlab, gitlab-api

I want all the public groups of a particular user in gitlab. Is there any API or any other way to achieve it.

`https://gitlab.com/api/v4/groups`
If I use this API without providing any authentication token, it gives me all the public groups in GITLAB. But my requirement is to get all public groups of a particular user(using user_id).

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to list a user's groups.

The closest way to do this would be to [list all groups](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/groups.html#list-groups) and then use the [memberships API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/members.html) to see if the user is in a particular group.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not answer the question :-(

Comment: @Tom in what way does this not answer the question?